# jQuery ajax call returns empty error if the content is empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I call the `getResult()` function everytime when `res.reply = 2`, but there are cases that `res` is empty. When the returned value is empty `console.log("error")` is invoked. This works in older versions of *jQuery Mobile*. Now the version is *1.3.2*.

```
function getResult()
{
    request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            ....
        },
        error: function() {         
            console.log("error");
        },
        success: function(res) {
            if(res.reply=='2') {
                getResult();
            }         
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Expecting help with jQuery 1.3.2 is a little... *optimistic*. Why don't you use a current version?

Comment: Hitting the `error` handler does not necessarily mean the response is empty - it most commonly means that a response could not be retrieved due to an error on the server. Check the network traffic in Firebug and your server logs for an error.

Comment: What error you are receiving ..you can check with `error : function (xhr,err){         
               console.log(xhr);console.log(err);
            }`

Comment: Because it is the latest version http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: console.log(xhr);console.log(err); returns
Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="OK"}
search...mbers=1 (line 136)
parsererror

Comment: does res always have the property reply ?

Comment: What are the cases when res is empty? Is it related to what gets passed in `data`? i think it's possible that the issue may be that the server doesn't know what to do with your input and passes back an error.

Comment: Also, it looks like this code will (effectively) infinite loop while this ajax request works correctly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
dataType: "json"
```

means: give me json, nothing else. an empty string is not json, so recieving an empty string means that it wasn't a success...

```
request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
        ....
    },
    error: function() {         
        console.log("error");
    },
    success: function(res) {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
        if(typeof response == 'object'){
            if(response.reply == '2') {
                getResult();
            }  
        } else {
              //response is empty 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like normally you do want a JSON response, so I wouldn't change your dataType to "text", instead I would get the server to return a valid JSON response even when the response is empty e.g. "{}" instead of "".